# Using Kepler GL without Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kepler.gl

I want to include large-scale maps in my current project to map some data on the country maps. I came across Kepler GL which does exactly that. I am using python for my project, but till now I have found only Jupyter notebook implementations of **Kepler GL**.

Is there any way to include and display maps **using Kepler GL with just python scripts and without Jupyter notebooks**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: [keplergl_cli](https://github.com/kylebarron/keplergl_cli). It's a good starting point for using Kepler from any IDE or from CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The way of using keplergl outside of a jupyter notebook is within a browser, after saving the map in html:

```py
from keplergl import KeperlGl

kmap = KeplerGl()
kmap.save_to_html(file_name="my_empty_kepler_map.html")
```

Then simply open the `.html` file with your browser.